Meta ios ads sdk tesmode
I just want to test META ads sdk in my ios APP. I set every necessary parameter.
     FBAdSettings.setLogLevel(.verbose)
     FBAdSettings.addTestDevice("b602d594afd2b0b327e07a06f36ca6a7e42546d0")
     FBAudienceNetworkAds.initialize(with: nil) { result in
         FBAdSettings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true)
     }

FBAdSettings.isTestMode() returns true after SDK was initialized.
Then I init my ad object and load it:
self.interstitial = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID")
self.interstitial.load()

I have even tried PLAYABLE#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID placement id.
But I see no_fill every time.
It works for my android app.
